# Starting debugging with DDD

Tags: debugging, ddd-debugger

I would like to use DDD to debug the source code of Gedit and GTK+. I start DDD by command ddd gedit. Now I can run the project and I found the source window but I can't see the sources of Gedit and GTK+ nor run the program line by line. How to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to recompile your sources adding debug symbols.

Look in the documentation of gedit to see how you can compile with them. There should be a Developers or Hackers section that explains how to do that.

Comment: Thanks! I found the solution at http://jameswestby.net/tips/tips/compiling-debian-package-for-debug.html

Comment: Now I have done that
dbkg -i gedit_2.26.1-0ubuntu1_i386.deb
I tried to start ddd by command 
ddd gedit_2.26.1-0ubuntu1_i386.deb
but I still can't debug the code.

Comment: no, you don't have to open the .deb file, but the executable one (open a shell, type 'which gedit' without quotes and open with ddd the file it outputs)

Comment: I typed which gedit and it outputs
/usr/bin/gedit
But still 
ddd /usr/bin/gedit 
says no debugging symbols. I think this is the version which was installed already. However, for the new package 
which gedit_2.26.14 
outputs nothing.

Comment: Any ideas why it outputs nothing?